# How to run Distinct() method with Split() method in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, linq

MY SQL Table has data as separated with comma like:

- Wordpress, MVC
- AngularJS, MVC, CSharp

I have a string array in my MVC 4 project:

```
@{
    foreach (var pot in Model)
    {
        string str = pot.Tags;
        string[] strT = str.Split(',');

        foreach (var poo in strT)

        {
            <button type="button" class="md-button md-warn @poo.ToLower().Replace(" ", "")">@poo</button>
        }
    }
}
```

And result of this function:

```
<button type="button" class="md-button md-warn wordpress">Wordpress</button>
<button type="button" class="md-button md-warn mvc"> MVC</button>
<button type="button" class="md-button md-warn angularjs">AngularJS</button>
<button type="button" class="md-button md-warn mvc"> MVC</button>
<button type="button" class="md-button md-warn csharp"> CSharp</button>
```

Also, I'm trying `.Distinct()` method to remove repeated data after split, but I couldn't work it. Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not clear what your actual problem is? You don't seem to be even calling `Distinct` in your code and you haven't given us any details of what is going wrong when you do try it. Are you getting compile errors? Duplicate results still present? Removing results you don't expect it to? Something else?

Comment: @Chris , I used .Distinct().ToList(); method to all part of my function but when I run the project Visual Studio not giving any error and project working like nothing happen, so duplicated contents not removing. So, I have no idea to what should I have to do.

Comment: The problem is if you don't show us the code that is not working its really hard for us to understand what is going wrong for you. For example right now I know for a fact that the above code is not the code you are having problems with (because `Distinct` doesn't appear anywhere in it). I have no idea how different the above is though. Where do you have Distinct? Do you have any other changes?  Who knows? So put the code into your question that you are actually having a problem with.

Comment: @Chris, I can't edit my question right not but here is my not working part: string[] strT = str.Split(',').Distinct().ToArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to only display unique tags then you would need to flatten the multiple collections first into one sequence using [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to be able to properly use `Distinct` to display the buttons without duplicates.

```
@{
    var tags = Model.SelectMany(pot => pot.Tags
                        .Split(new [] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(s => s.Trim())
                    )
                    .Distinct();

    foreach (var tag in tags) {
        <button type="button" class="md-button md-warn @tag.ToLower()">@tag</button>
    }
}
```

Which given the data provided in the example would result in

```
<button type="button" class="md-button md-warn wordpress">Wordpress</button>
<button type="button" class="md-button md-warn mvc">MVC</button>
<button type="button" class="md-button md-warn angularjs">AngularJS</button>
<button type="button" class="md-button md-warn csharp">CSharp</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope you can use `Distinct` like this

```
string[] strT = str.Split(',').Distinct().ToArray();
```

Another way would be making the `List<string>` instead of array.

```
List<string> strT = str.Split(',').Distinct().ToList();
```

You can read more on [List.Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt253621.aspx) and [Remove Duplicates](https://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-duplicates-list)

Comment: As my search before publish the question, I found the same method as your answer, but It's not working. It's not giving any error and it's working like nothing happen. I don't understand to where is the mistake.

Comment: @EmirhanÖZKAN The problem is that calling distinct on multiple sequences is only going to remove duplicates in individual sequences. It does not cater to the other sequences that may have duplicates of another sequence. You have to merge the sequences together and then look for distinct items in the merged collection.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi for the explanation. Truly a gentleman spirit. :)

Comment: @MohitShrivastava , May you give an advice to how to merge them? :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
var Model = new List<string>(){ "a,b,c", "b,c,d" };


foreach (var pot in Model.SelectMany(item => item.Split(',')).Distinct())
{
    string[] strT = pot.Split(',');

    foreach (var poo in strT)

    {
        Console.WriteLine(poo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@{
List<string> ListWithDups = new List<string>();

foreach (var pot in Model)
{
    string str = pot.Tags;
    ListWithDups.InsertRange(ListWithDups.Count,str.Split(','));
}
ListWithoutDups = ListWithDups.Distinct().ToList();
foreach (var poo in ListWithoutDups)
{
    <button type="button" class="md-button md-warn @poo.ToLower().Replace(" ", "")">@poo</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a System.Linq reference and use Distinc() method. 
See the run example in: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oJKClC

```
using System;
using System.Linq; // Add the Linq referece

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = "Wordpress, MVC, AngularJS, MVC, CSharp, Wordpress, MVC, AngularJS, MVC, CSharp";
        string[] strT = str.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Split(',');
        strT = strT.Distinct().ToArray();
        foreach (var poo in strT)

        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("<button type='button' class='md-button md-warn {0}'>{0}</button>", poo.ToLower().Trim()));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Code:

```
  var str1= str.Split(',').Select(c=>c.Trim()).Distinct().ToList();
```

Another solution Is

```
var str1= str.Split(',').Select(c=>c.Trim()).GroupBy(c => c).ToList();
```